# Nextjs and strapi how to sort by creation time?

Tags: sorting, next.js, strapi

Nextjs and strapi how to sort by creation time? The official document provides a sorting method, but there is no way to start. Writing according to the document is invalid. This is my code. Can you please advise on how to arrange it in reverse order of creation time?

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
    const category = await fetchDataFromApi(
        `/api/categories?filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}`
    );
    const products = await fetchDataFromApi(
        `/api/products?populate=*&[filters][category][slug][$eq]=${slug}&pagination[page]=2&pagination[pageSize]=${maxResult}`
    );

    return {
        props: {
            category,
            products,
            slug,
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: qs.stringify({ sort: { createdAt: 'desc‘ }, populate: … })